Gaussian processes for Machine Learning, Rasmussen, Exercise 5.2
Problem
Consider the difference between the log marginal likelihood given by: $\sum_i \log p(y_i|\{y_j, j<i\})$, and the LOO-CV using log probability which is given by $\sum_i \log p(y_i| \{y_j, j\neq i\})$. From the viewpoint of the marginal likelihood the LOO-CV conditions too much on the data. Show that the expected LOO-CV loss is greater than the expected marginal likelihood.
Attempt at Solution
We wish to show
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_i \log p(y_i| \{y_j, j\neq i\})\right] &\leq \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_i \log p(y_i| \{y_j, j < i\})\right] \\
\iff \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_i \log \frac{p(\{y_i\})}{p(\{y_j, j\neq i\})}\right] &\leq \mathbb{E}\left[\log p(\{y_i\})\right] \\
\iff n\mathbb{E}\left[ \log p(\{y_i\}) \right] - \sum_i \mathbb{E}\left[\log p(\{y_j, j\neq i\})\right] &\leq \mathbb{E}\left[ \log p(\{y_i\}) \right] \\
\iff (n-1)\mathbb{E}\left[ \log p(\{y_i\}) \right] &\leq \sum_i \mathbb{E}\left[\log p(\{y_j, j\neq i\})\right] 
\end{align*}
$$
but here is where I'm stuck. I was thinking maybe we can use Jensen's to show that
$$(n-1)\mathbb{E}\left[ \log p(\{y_i\}) \right] \leq (n-1) \log \mathbb{E}[p(\{y_i\})]$$
but I'm not sure if that helps.
Also, I suppose we can relate the probabilities on the RHS and the LHS through marginalization, i.e. $p(\{y_j, j\neq i\}) = \int_\mathbb{R}p(\{y_j\})dy_i$ but I'm not sure how to prove $(n-1)\mathbb{E}\left[ \log p(\{y_j\}) \right] \leq \sum_i \mathbb{E}\left[\log \int_\mathbb{R}p(\{y_j\})dy_i\right]$.
Any hints appreciated!
